# Excel VBA - Splitting/Sorting data into report table

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, split

I am trying to sort my raw data into report format. for example my raw data looks like figure below:

> Team names, Employee names, country they have traveled, Quarter of the
>   year

[image]

I want my data to be split/sort in given format like row contains name of employees in team1 (let's say we have 6 employees in team1) and column contains all 4 quarters, and solution looks like a matrix (6x4) where country name is filled in cells. 
Also if employee has visited US & UK in same quarter, his cell shows both the names of country in same cell.

Figure 2 is the solution I am looking for:
[image]

Please help me, I tried writing this VBA code and successfully sorted employees names in team, BUT i have no idea how do i fill the cells w.r.t. Quarters?

```
Sub JMP()
Dim team1 As String
Dim team2 As String
Dim team3 As String
Dim team 4 As String

Dim Q1 As String
Dim Q2 As String
Dim Q3 As String
Dim Q4 As String

Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

team1 = Sheets("MasterSheet").Range("I1").Value
team2 = Sheets("MasterSheet").Range("O1").Value
team3 = Sheets("MasterSheet").Range("U1").Value

Q1 = Sheets("MasterSheet").Range("J1").Value
Q2 = Sheets("MasterSheet").Range("K1").Value
Q3 = Sheets("MasterSheet").Range("L1").Value
Q4 = Sheets("MasterSheet").Range("M1").Value

finalrow = Sheets("MasterSheet").Range("B200").End(xlUp).Row
i = 0
For i = 1 To 100
     If Cells(i, 2) = team1 And Cells(i, 5) = Q1 Then
            Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 4)).Copy
            Range("I100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    'ElseIf Cells(i, 2) = team 1 And Cells(i, 5) = Q3 Then
            'Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 4)).Copy
            'Range("I100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    'ElseIf Cells(i, 2) = Russia And Cells(i, 5) = Q4 Then
            'Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 4)).Copy
            'Range("I100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    End If

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Any reason that you can't use a pivot table?

Comment: @cronos2546 - how will you get `UK+US` to show up in the pivot table value box? Although, I agree using the row / column structure and page filtering for teams with a pivot table could be a great place to start.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman you wouldn't be able to accomplish that particular cell value without a new calculated column (which could be VBA powered), however, it seemed that a pivot table could fill many of the design objectives that the OP requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more array based solution.

```
Sub reportTeam()
    Dim o As Long, n As Long, r As Long, t As Long
    Dim vTEAM As Variant, vTEAMs As Variant, vNAMEs As Variant
    Dim wsREP As Worksheet

    Set wsREP = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    ReDim vTEAMs(1 To 1)

    With Worksheets("MasterSheet")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Key2:=.Columns(4), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                        Key3:=.Columns(2), Order3:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                vTEAMs = .Cells.Value2
                n = 0
                ReDim vNAMEs(1 To 2, 1 To 1)
                For t = LBound(vTEAMs, 1) To UBound(vTEAMs, 1)
                    n = n + 1
                    If t = UBound(vTEAMs, 1) Then
                        vNAMEs(1, UBound(vNAMEs, 2)) = n
                        vNAMEs(2, UBound(vNAMEs, 2)) = vTEAMs(t, 1)
                    ElseIf vTEAMs(t, 1) <> vTEAMs(t + 1, 1) Then
                        vNAMEs(1, UBound(vNAMEs, 2)) = n
                        vNAMEs(2, UBound(vNAMEs, 2)) = vTEAMs(t, 1)
                        ReDim Preserve vNAMEs(1 To 2, 1 To UBound(vNAMEs, 2) + 1)
                        n = 0
                    End If
                Next t
            End With
        End With
    End With

    t = 1
    With wsREP
        .UsedRange.ClearContents
        For n = LBound(vNAMEs, 2) To UBound(vNAMEs, 2)
            ReDim vTEAM(1 To vNAMEs(1, n) + 1, 1 To 5)
            r = 1
            vTEAM(r, 1) = vNAMEs(2, n)
            vTEAM(r, 2) = "Q1": vTEAM(r, 3) = "Q2": vTEAM(r, 4) = "Q3": vTEAM(r, 5) = "Q4"
            r = r + 1
            vTEAM(r, 1) = vTEAMs(t, 2)
            vTEAM(r, Right(vTEAMs(t, 4), 1) + 1) = vTEAMs(t, 3)
            r = r + 1

            For t = Application.Match(vNAMEs(2, n), Application.Index(vTEAMs, 0, 1), 0) + 1 To _
                    Application.Match(vNAMEs(2, n), Application.Index(vTEAMs, 0, 1))
                If vTEAMs(t, 2) = vTEAMs(t - 1, 2) And vTEAMs(t, 4) = vTEAMs(t - 1, 4) Then
                    vTEAM(r - 1, Right(vTEAMs(t, 4), 1) + 1) = _
                      vTEAM(r - 1, Right(vTEAMs(t, 4), 1) + 1) & Chr(43) & vTEAMs(t, 3)
                Else
                    vTEAM(r, 1) = vTEAMs(t, 2)
                    vTEAM(r, Right(vTEAMs(t, 4), 1) + 1) = vTEAMs(t, 3)
                    r = r + 1
                End If
            Next t

            With .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
                With .Resize(UBound(vTEAM, 1), UBound(vTEAM, 2)).Offset(0, Abs(.Column > 1) * 2)
                    .Cells = vTEAM
                End With
            End With

        Next n

    End With
End Sub
```

I gathered from your code that the original data was on a worksheet named **MasterSheet** but I could find no reference to the report worksheet. I used **Sheet2** for the reporting.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the example how to prepare the report using some SQL processing and loops:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateReport()

    Dim objConnection As Object
    Dim lngPosition As Long
    Dim strTeamName As Variant
    Dim objRecordSet As Object
    Dim arrData() As String
    Dim arrEmployees As Variant
    Dim lngEmployee As Long
    Dim lngQuarter As Long
    Dim arrPlaces As Variant

    ' open ADODB connection to this workbook
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objConnection.Open _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "User ID=Admin;" & _
        "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';" & _
        "Mode=Read;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;"";"
    ' prepare target worksheet for output
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Delete
    lngPosition = 1
    ' get names of teams
    Set objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute( _
        "SELECT DISTINCT [Team Name] FROM [Sheet1$];")
    ' process each team
    For Each strTeamName In objRecordSet.GetRows
        ' get names of particular team employees
        Set objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute( _
            "SELECT DISTINCT [Traveller's Name] FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE " & _
            "[Team Name] = '" & strTeamName & "';")
        arrEmployees = objRecordSet.GetRows
        ' prepare resulting array
        ReDim arrData(UBound(arrEmployees, 2) + 1, 4)
        arrData(0, 0) = strTeamName
        arrData(0, 1) = "Q1"
        arrData(0, 2) = "Q2"
        arrData(0, 3) = "Q3"
        arrData(0, 4) = "Q4"
        ' process each employee of the team
        For lngEmployee = 0 To UBound(arrEmployees, 2)
            arrData(lngEmployee + 1, 0) = arrEmployees(0, lngEmployee)
            ' process each quarter for the employee of the team
            For lngQuarter = 1 To 4
                ' get all visited places of the employee of the team for the quarter
                Set objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute( _
                    "SELECT DISTINCT [Country/Place] FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE " & _
                    "[Team Name] = '" & strTeamName & "' AND " & _
                    "[Traveller's Name] = '" & arrEmployees(0, lngEmployee) & "' AND " & _
                    "[Quarter] = 'Q" & lngQuarter & "';")
                If Not objRecordSet.EOF Then
                    ' if there are any places then join them and write to array
                    arrPlaces = objRecordSet.GetRows
                    arrPlaces = Application.Index(arrPlaces, , 0) ' make 1d from 2d array
                    arrData(lngEmployee + 1, lngQuarter) = Join(arrPlaces, "+")
                End If
            Next
        Next
        ' put populated array for the team to the sheet
        Output Sheets("Sheet2"), 1, lngPosition, arrData
        lngPosition = lngPosition + 6 ' shift to the right
    Next

End Sub

Sub Output(objSheet As Worksheet, lngTop As Long, lngLeft As Long, arrCells As Variant)
    With objSheet
        .Select
        .Range(.Cells(lngTop, lngLeft), .Cells(UBound(arrCells, 1) + lngTop, UBound(arrCells, 2) + lngLeft)).Value = arrCells
    End With
End Sub
```

I populated the source worksheet `Sheet1` with values as follows:

[image: source worksheet]

Then the resulting report looks like as follows:

[image: report]

Note that you can get source data from any other workbook, just replace `ThisWorkbook.FullName` with actual path. Any changes made to the source workbook must be saved before the macro launched, since the connection should be done to the file, containing actual data. It works on 64-bit version Excel 2010 for me. To make it compatible with `.xls` and Excel 2003 (where the provider `ACE.OLEDB.12.0` isn't installed) you have to replace `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;` with `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;`, and also in extended properties `Excel 12.0 Macro;` / `Excel 12.0;` with `Excel 8.0;`.

Comment: First of all, Thank you so much :). I don't know SQL programming so still trying to figure out your code but its working. But if i am using this code and have team names "team 10"/ "team 11 ", in output they are coming in between "team 1" & "team 2". How do i rectify that situation?

Comment: @Shikha Teams just put in order sorted as strings. Why not to use team names like `team01`, `team02`, ... , `team11`?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you.  You'll need to update the sheetnames for `wsData` (the sheet your original data is on), `wsDest` (the sheet you want to output the results to), and `rTeams` (the range of cells that contains the original data).

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim cTeams As Collection
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim rTeams As Range
    Dim TeamCell As Range
    Dim aTeamData() As Variant
    Dim vTeam As Variant
    Dim sFirst As String
    Dim sUnqTeams As String
    Dim sTeam As String
    Dim lQuarter As Long
    Dim lNameIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set cTeams = New Collection
    Set wsData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rTeams = wsData.Range("A2", wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

    For Each TeamCell In rTeams.Cells
        sTeam = CStr(TeamCell.Value)
        If InStr(1, "|" & sUnqTeams & "|", "|" & sTeam & "|", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            sUnqTeams = sUnqTeams & "|" & sTeam
            ReDim aTeamData(1 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rTeams, sTeam) + 1, 1 To 5)
            aTeamData(1, 1) = sTeam
            aTeamData(1, 2) = "Q1"
            aTeamData(1, 3) = "Q2"
            aTeamData(1, 4) = "Q3"
            aTeamData(1, 5) = "Q4"

            Set rFound = rTeams.Find(sTeam, rTeams.Cells(rTeams.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                sFirst = rFound.Address
                Do
                    For i = 2 To UBound(aTeamData, 1)
                        If Len(aTeamData(i, 1)) = 0 Then
                            aTeamData(i, 1) = rFound.Offset(, 1).Value
                            lNameIndex = i
                            Exit For
                        ElseIf aTeamData(i, 1) = rFound.Offset(, 1).Value Then
                            lNameIndex = i
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next i
                    lQuarter = Right(rFound.Offset(, 3).Value, 1) + 1
                    If Len(aTeamData(lNameIndex, lQuarter)) = 0 Then
                        aTeamData(lNameIndex, lQuarter) = rFound.Offset(, 2).Value
                    Else
                        aTeamData(lNameIndex, lQuarter) = aTeamData(lNameIndex, lQuarter) & "+" & rFound.Offset(, 2).Value
                    End If
                    Set rFound = rTeams.FindNext(rFound)
                Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst
                cTeams.Add aTeamData, sTeam
            End If
        End If
    Next TeamCell

    wsDest.Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(aTeamData, 2)).EntireColumn.Clear
    For Each vTeam In cTeams
        wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(2).Resize(UBound(vTeam, 1), UBound(vTeam, 2)).Value = vTeam
    Next vTeam
    wsDest.Range("1:2").EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp

End Sub
```

Comment: fwiw, I think the reported data was intended to be across columns (e.g. Team2 to the right of Team1).

Comment: @tigeravatar : Thanks for your quick reply, although i am facing a problem with "Msg Box"? i don't want any msg box but as soon as i am removing text written for MsgBox , i am getting error.

Comment: Oh, the message boxes were for me testing and debugging the code and I forgot to take them out when I posted the solution.  I'll edit the post to remove them.